# async/await: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int[]'

Tags: c#

I am using C# 7.1 and below async/await code give me error, `Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'int[]'`

What is the solution for it?

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task1 = Task.FromResult(3);
        Task task2 = Task.FromResult(5);
        Task task3 = Task.FromResult(7);

        int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I want to return result like

`// "results" contains { 3, 5, 7 }`

Comment: `WhenAll` returns void and not `int[]`

Comment: no kidding you want convert void to int[]?!?!

Comment: I want to return result like `// "results" contains { 3, 5, 7 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how it must be:

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.FromResult(3);
Task<int> task2 = Task.FromResult(5);
Task<int> task3 = Task.FromResult(7);

int[] results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

You were casting `Task<int>` to base type `Task`.